# How to share dynamically generated secrets between Docker containers

Tags: security, docker, docker-compose, shared-secret

I have linked together a couple of Docker containers that use each others API endpoints. These API endpoints are protected by a **secret** and are **generated on container startup**. I'm looking for a **safe** way to share these secrets between those services without doing anything *static* (e.g. hardcoding). These services are created and linked together using `docker-compose` and it is possible for the secret to be overridden using an environment variable. This behavior is not encouraged for production however.

**What is in my case the safest way to distribute these secrets?**

---

## Things I have considered:

- *Using a central data container which stores these secrets as a file. The clients can then link to this container and lookup the secret in the file.*

This huge downside this approach has is that it limits the containers to run on the same node.

- *Generating a  `docker-compose` file with these random secrets hardcoded into them before deploying the containers.*

The downside to this approach would be that it wouldn't be possible to simply use the `docker-compose` file but limiting yourself to a bash script to generate something as mission critical as these secrets. This would also not adhere to my sidenote that the solution should be dynamically adaptable to secret changes.

---

## Sidenote

Ultimately, I would prefer it if the solution could also adapt dynamically to secret changes. For example, when a container fails, it will restart automatically, thus also generating a new secret.

Comment: Run something like `etcd` in a third container and use that as a secrets registry?  This gets you the dynamic updates you're looking for, and would not limit you to containers on the same host.

Comment: Consul is a similar option to etcd, they're both designed to enable late binding of an applications components, avoiding the need for static configuration. You should also look at vault which can use consul as its HA backend.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor How do I create one Consul instance per node and then link it to all the services on that node? I'm talking about Docker here.

Comment: See: http://jlordiales.me/2015/02/03/registrator/

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Thanks